# Audio element without 'controls' disappears in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome, audio

Take a look at this example http://jsfiddle.net/39gdA/

```
<audio controls>
    <source src="audio/no-audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
    Your browser does not support this audio format.
</audio>

audio {
    background: yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    border: solid 1px #000
}
```

Audio element shows just fine but as soon as you remove 'controls' from the audio tag, it disappears. Though in Firefox it works as expected. Is there a way how to keep the audio element without showing the controls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no clear indication as how the audio tag should look when the controls attribute is absent in the [spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/single-page.html#attr-media-controls). So it is likely to be browser dependent. Of course with a video tag you will have the video frames to display even with no controls but in the case of an audio tag you just have "sound" to relay to the destination (read the speakers, headphones ...).

If you decide not to use/set the default browser controls with omitting the controls attribute (be it dynamically or not) you ***should*** provide your own set of controls.

You can accomplish what you want with JavaScript and a div wrapper for your audio tag. An example as follows:

```
<div id="audioWrapper">
    <audio id="myAudio" controls>
    <source src="your.mp3" type="audio/mpeg" />
    Your browser does not support this audio format.
    </audio>
</div>
<div id="showAudio">Show</div>
<div id="hideAudio">Hide</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var audio = document.getElementById('myAudio');
var showButton = document.getElementById('showAudio');
var hideButton = document.getElementById('hideAudio');
showButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    audio.style.display="block";
},
false);
hideButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
    audio.style.display="none";
},
 false);
</script>
```

CSS

```
#audioWrapper {
background: yellow;
width: 200px;
height: 100px;
display: block;
border: solid 1px #000;
}
audio{
width: 100%;
}
```

Also keep in mind that there could be minimum width or height for the audio controls of the browser to display correctly (so that it won't overlap with your background).